# Can't open a PDF after a maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven, stream

I have a Java application and I have a user manual, that is available for the users, which is a ressource of my program.

My project is build with Maven, I have several project. In my GUI project I have the userManual.pdf in the following path :
src\main\resources\userManual\userManual.pdf

Under Eclipse IDE, I run my main project and when I click on the user manual button the PDF file is going to be opened. But when I build my project I have an Internal Runtime Error in a option pane :
An internal error occured (The file:.\userManual\userManual.pdf doesn't exist.).
The application is most likely in an inappropriate state, thus will nox exit.

My code :

```
File manual = new File(ManualBar.class.getClassLoader().getResource("./userManual/userManual.pdf").getPath());

try {
   Desktop.getDesktop().open(manual);
} catch (IOException e1) {
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                               "The user manual is not available", 
                               "User manual is missing",
                               JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

I think I don't call correctly my ressource or it's not to the correct place.

Comment: Try changing to `/userManual/userManual.pdf` (without the initial dot)

Comment: I have already tested this and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you filtering your resources by configuration in your pom file?

Comment: I don't know. I'm a beginner in Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a resource inside a jar as a `File` instance. It works within your IDE because Eclipse unpacks everything inside a temporary folder so the resource is an actual file in the filesystem. However, when packaged inside a jar, it is not a `File` any longer.

Since the [`Desktop.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) method requires a `File` object, you need to get an `InputStream` of your resource, copy it to a `File` in a temporary folder and open that new file.

Using Java 7, this can be written as:

```
Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".pdf");
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/userManual/userManual.pdf")) {
    Files.copy(is, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile.toFile());
```

Comment: When I run in Eclipse IDE I have an exception : java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\fred37b\AppData\Local\Temp\1488624516076161268.tmp I try to built in maven now

Comment: @Fred37b See my edit, you can add StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING but I don't think it is necessary since a new temp file will be created everytime

Comment: even with Files.copy(is, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING), I have an IOException that it throw on the tempFile.toFile()

Comment: `toFile` method does not throw `IOException` so it's unclear what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry, the line Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile.toFile()); throw the IOException

Comment: `IOException` is thrown from `open` if no application can be found to open the extension. Did you copy my snippet with ".pdf" as extension in createTempFile? Is so, if Adobe (or some other) the default application for opening pdf files?

Comment: You're right, I forgot the PDF, sorry. It's works on Eclipse IDE, I run a maven built. Thanks